# Why am i getting this error, while unit testing ngrx-effect

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, ngrx, jasmine-marbles

I'm writing unit tests for ngrx effects. I tried it all but it seems that i can't get past this error:

```
Expected $[0].notification.kind = 'E' to equal 'N'.
Expected $[0].notification.value = undefined to equal Object({ vendors: [ Object({ id: 1234, code: 'tst', name: 'test', freePlay: true, freeSpin: false, disabled: true, active: false }) ], type: '[CasinoVendors API] Get Vendors Success' }).
Expected $[0].notification.error = TypeError: Cannot read property 'sort' of undefined to equal undefined.
Expected $[0].notification.hasValue = false to equal true.
```

The effect that I'm trying to test is:

```
getVendors$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(CasinoVendorsActions.getVendors),
    concatMap(() => this.casinoVendorsSvc.getVendors()
      .pipe(
        map((data: any) => {
          let vendors: VendorModel[] = data

          return CasinoVendorsActions.getVendorsSuccess({vendors: vendors});
        })
      ))
    )
  );
```

the unit test:

```
describe('getVendors', () => {
    it('should return a stream with getVendorsSuccess action', () => {
      const vendors: VendorModel[] = [{
        id: 1234,
        code: 'tst',
        name: 'test',
        freePlay: true,
        freeSpin: false,
        disabled: true,
        active: false,
      }];
      const action = CasinoVendorsActions.getVendors();
      const outcome = CasinoVendorsActions.getVendorsSuccess({vendors: vendors});

      actions$ = hot('-a', { a: action });
      const response = cold('-a|', { a: vendors });

      casinoVendorsSvc.getVendors.and.returnValue(response);

      const expected = cold('--b', { b: outcome });

      expect(effects.getVendors$).toBeObservable(expected);
    });
  });
```

Since the effect returns action "getVendorsSuccess" filled with correct data, i suspect that the problem is in this part:

```
const expected = cold('--b', { b: outcome });

expect(effects.getVendors$).toBeObservable(expected);
```

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You read vendors in your effect as  `let vendors: VendorModel[] = data.payload;`

But your service returns `const vendors: VendorModel[] = [...];`

You probably have to wrap it in an object as `{data: (vendors: VendorModel[])}`

Comment: That's true. I made a mistake while copying effect. For the sake of simplicity while trying to test the effect, i modified the effect to return the unchanged data, but when posting this question i posted the original effect.
I edited the original question and modified the effect with the correct code.
The error remains

Comment: If you have a working reproduction, i'm happy to take a look